# How to Parrallelize Read operation in MongoDB in Spark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo

I am using mongodb/mongo-hadoop 
(https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage#python-example) but was confused on how I can do parallel read operations.

By parallel read operations means, do concurrent read operation on my MongoDB index. I have indexed my DB based on Timestamp, and want to query data bw T1-T2, T3-T4, etc. parallelly.